# Eliminar informação da textbox quando existe reload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

Estou a criar uma página web asp.net e queria que quando fosse recarregado o site ou premida a tecla "f5" todos os dados da textbox passassem a "".

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o seu cenário? Está com algum problema do ViewState ou PostBack?

Comment: Eu não sei como fazer por isso é que estou a perguntar! Não sei nem por onde começar

Comment: Mas o que está acontecendo? você preenche os campos e ao atualizar a página os valores antigos são exibidos?

Comment: sim isso mesmo. as textboxs continuam lá com os valores

Comment: Você tem algum componente que está com o atributo `AutoPostBack="true"` ?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Não

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só colocar as textboxs a "" (null) quando a página faz Load()

Answer (score 0):

Como você informou que não está utilizando o `PostBack` para nenhuma operação, você pode desligar o ViewState. Na declaração de page no seu `.aspx` adicione o atributo `EnableViewState="false"`.

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" ...
```